# Append full PDF file to FOP PDF

Tags: java, apache-fop

I have an xml file already being created and rendered as a PDF sent over a servlet:

```
TraxInputHandler input = new TraxInputHandler(
   new File(XML_LOCATION+xmlFile+".xml"),
   new File(XSLT_LOCATION)
);
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

//driver is just `new Driver()`
synchronized (driver) {
  driver.reset();
  driver.setRenderer(Driver.RENDER_PDF);
  driver.setOutputStream(out);
  input.run(driver);
}

//response is HttpServletResponse
byte[] content = out.toByteArray();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setContentLength(content.length);
response.getOutputStream().write(content);
response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

This is all working perfectly fine.

However, I now have another PDF file that I need to include in the output.  This is just a totally separate `.pdf` file that I was given.  Is there any way that I can append this file either to the response, the driver, `out`, or anything else to include it in the response to the client?  Will that even work?  Or is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We also use FOP to generate some documents, and we accept uploaded documents, all of which we eventually combine into a single PDF.

You can't just send them sequentially out the stream, because the combined result needs a proper PDF file header, metadata, etc.

We use the [iText library](http://itextpdf.com/) to combine the files, starting off with

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(/*String*/fileName);
reader.consolidateNamedDestinations();
```

We later loop through adding pages from each pdf to the new combined destination pdf, adjusting the bookmark / page numbers as we go.

AFAIK, FOP doesn't provide this sort of functionality.